# Writing to two text files using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I cannot write this value into two separate text files. It only writes to one.

```
Public Class frmIceCream
Dim tw As System.IO.TextWriter
```

Then in the form load I have the following:

```
tw = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\sundae.txt", True)
tw.WriteLine("5")

tw = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\banana.txt", True)
tw.WriteLine("5")
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing that shows it is only writing into one file? (ie, which file is it writing to?)

Answer (score 2):

For the shortest possible code snippet, you can use [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\sundae.txt", "5")
File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\banana.txt", "5")
```

If you want to keep using your approach, it is generally preferable to keep your file open for as short as possible. I would wrap your file operations into `Using` blocks, this way `StreamWriter` is disposed (and closed) automatically:

```
Using tw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\sundae.txt", True)
  tw.WriteLine("5")
End Using
Using tw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\banana.txt", True)
  tw.WriteLine("5")
End Using
```

Notice here that even though you are technically using different `tw` objects, you can keep the same name, if it makes code more readable for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't reuse the variable until you close the other file.  It is probably easier to have two files open. Try this:

```
Dim tw1 as System.IO.TextWriter, tw2 as System.IO.TextWriter

tw1 = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\sundae.txt", True) 
tw1.WriteLine("5")
tw2 = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\banana.txt", True)
tw2.WriteLine("5")
```

Comment: Wow. This site is so awesome. Thank you so much I will give it a try. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are most likely dealing with is that the first text file is empty.

Writing to the harddrive is expensive, so the TextWriter uses a buffer that holds some amount of text and then writes it all at once. Try using `tw.Flush()` to write whatever is left in the buffer then use `tw.Close()` to free the resource.

This should work:

```
tw = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\sundae.txt", True)
tw.WriteLine("5")
tw.Flush()
tw.Close()

tw = New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\F\Documents\Temp junk\banana.txt", True)
tw.WriteLine("5")
tw.Flush()
tw.Close()
```